# fancybox thumbs strange behavior

Tags: jquery, image, fancybox

I'm using fancybox thumbs as the web page (fancyapps.com) says I should, but I can't make it work correctly.

```
<script src="javascript/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<link href="jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="javascript/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>

<script>
$('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
      prevEffect : 'none',
      nextEffect : 'none',
      closeBtn  : true,
      arrows    : true,
      nextClick : true,
      helpers : {
            title : {
                 type : 'inside'
            },
            thumbs : {
                 width  : 50,
                 height : 50
            }
      }
});
</script>

<div class="cell"><a class="fancybox-thumbs" data-fancybox-group="thumb" href="images/image00_b.jpg" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet">
<img src="images/image00_s.jpg"/></a></div>

...same for 4 images!!
```

The result is:

(CHECK THE PICT)
http://s2.subirimagenes.com/otros/previo/thump_9204774wrong.jpg

The first 4 images are ok. After that, the "image04_b" image is repeated.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please post the full code. You omitted the part that's actually causing the problem.

Comment: try validating your document. it seems you forget to close a tag properly

Comment: I really really sorry. I'm an idiot. It was missing a last "</a>" That was the problem. Thanks!